# Google Apps Script - convert xlsx to sheet overwriting the existing one

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, overwrite

i'm facing a real big issue trying to convert an xlsx file to google sheet overwriting day by day the same file.
Here below the code that generates every day a new file .sheet but I really need to overwrite the existing one in order to be able to update a google data studio dashboard with the updated data.
Can you please help me?

```
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(fileName) {
  try {

    fileName = fileName || "GDS_Stock_Positioning.xlsx";

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = Drive.Files.get("1g5oIY5qeH5tNkMBGIzj1ddqX9DCXqJrz").parents[0].id;
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: excelFile.getName(),
      mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
      parents: [{id: "1g5oIY5qeH5tNkMBGIzj1ddqX9DCXqJrz"}],
    };

    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    Drive.Files.remove(fileId)

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }

}

function DeleteOldFiles() {
  var Folders = new Array(
    '1g5oIY5qeH5tNkMBGIzj1ddqX9DCXqJrz',
    '1g5oIY5qeH5tNkMBGIzj1ddqX9DCXqJrz'
  );
  var Files;

  Logger.clear();

  for (var key in Folders) {
    Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Folders[key])
    Files = Folder.getFiles();
    
    Logger.log('Opening Folder: ' + Folder.getName());

    while (Files.hasNext()) {
      var File = Files.next();

      if (new Date() - File.getLastUpdated() > 1 * 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
        File.setTrashed(true); // Places the file in the Trash folder
        //Drive.Files.remove(File.getId()); // Permanently deletes the file
        Logger.log('File ' + File.getName() + ' was deleted.');
      }
    }
  }

  if(Logger.getLog() != '')
    MailApp.sendEmail('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Backups have been removed from Google Drive', Logger.getLog());
}
```

Comment: The conversion is already working but you need to update the old file instead of creating a new one and removing the old, right?

Comment: yes exactly :( can you help me on this? I would be very greatful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to overwrite the existing Google Spreadsheet using the EXCEL data.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I think that this can be achieved by the method of "Files: update" of Drive API.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the variables of `xlsxFileName` and `spreadsheetId`. `xlsxFileName` is the filename of XLSX file. `spreadsheetId` id the Spreadsheet ID of Spreadsheet which is overwritten by the XLSX data.

```
function myFunction() {
  const xlsxFileName = "###";  // Please set the filename of XLSX file.
  const spreadsheetId = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID. This Spreadsheet is overwritten by EXCEL data.

  const xlsx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(xlsxFileName || "GDS_Stock_Positioning.xlsx");
  if (!xlsx.hasNext()) throw new Error("No excel file.");
  Drive.Files.update({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, spreadsheetId, xlsx.next().getBlob());
}
```

- When you run this script, the Spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId` is overwritten by the XLSX data of `xlsxFileName` or `GDS_Stock_Positioning.xlsx`. If `xlsxFileName` is not used, `GDS_Stock_Positioning.xlsx` is used. This is from your script.

#### IMPORTANT:

- **This script overwites the existing Spreadsheet. So please be careful. I would like to recommend to use a sample Spreadsheet for testing the script.**

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)

Comment: Many thanks, but it returns an error: ReferenceError: Drive is not defined (line 7, file "Code")Dismiss .

Comment: The code I posted is this one: function overwrite() {
  const xlsxFileName = "GDS_Stock_Positioning";  // Please set the filename of XLSX file.
  const spreadsheetId = "1yyXLujTXnDEaRSUghKtVl0tGp588AuhMlCHKDdL2EbY";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID. This Spreadsheet is overwritten by EXCEL data.

  const xlsx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(xlsxFileName || "GDS_Stock_Positioning.xlsx");
  if (!xlsx.hasNext()) throw new Error("No excel file.");
  Drive.Files.update({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, spreadsheetId, xlsx.next().getBlob());
}

Comment: Should I include this somewhere in the previous code or should I run this as it is alone? My goal is the overwrite the google sheet every day with the data included in the xlsx . Thanks a lot for your kind help :)

Comment: @Laura Premoli Thank you for replying. At first, I apologize for my poor English skill. About `but it returns an error: ReferenceError: Drive is not defined`, it is considered that the reason of your issue is due to that you have never enabled Drive API at Advanced Google services. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) So can you confirm about it and test it again? By the way, when `spreadsheetId` is invalid value, an error occurs. Please be careful this.

Comment: thanks for your anwer :) you are very kind! I've enabled all the drive API, the error is still there.... is it the full code or do I have to include it somewhere in the initial code?

Comment: @Laura Premoli Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from `the error is still there`, I cannot understand about the error. Is the error `ReferenceError: Drive is not defined (line 7, file "Code")Dismiss`? In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the detail information of it? Because when I tested the script, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. From your additional information, I would like to confirm your current situation.

Comment: It works! It was an issue with the authorization, now everything get updated ;) thanks a lot for your super help!!

Comment: @tankaike: I have one more question sorry, how can I keep also the sheetId on each overwrite? I'm trying to link the sheet to a google data studio project and it seems that I have to keep the sheetId too.

Comment: @Laura Premoli About your new question, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @tankaike: no problem I made it working :) thanks a lot again for your support :) have a nice new year!

Comment: I tried but I just can't.... I've created a new question at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662752/google-apps-script-how-to-overwrite-an-excel-file-to-a-fix-id-google-sheet    can you please help me on this? thanks in advance for what you can do... have a lovely night. Laura