# How to overwrite an excel file to a fix ID google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I need to overwrite with an Excel file a fixed Google spreadsheet that keep both file ID and sheet ID .
Here below the code written in Google Apps Script that works but everytime generate a new id for the sheet.

```
function overwrite() {
  const xlsxFileName = "XXX.xlsx";  // Please set the filename of XLSX file.
  const spreadsheetId = "1JnsV5Vpp0xXj1fNyDeKV04PReYGN4v2oBVcQb6bvBUA";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID. This Spreadsheet is overwritten by EXCEL data.
  
  const xlsx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(xlsxFileName || "XXX.xlsx");
  if (!xlsx.hasNext()) throw new Error("No excel file.");
  Drive.Files.update({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, spreadsheetId, xlsx.next().getBlob());
  
}
```

My need is to import the information included in a specific Excel sheet into a specific sheet in Google Sheet. My goal is to be able to keep the spreadsheetID and sheetID in order to be able to link a dashboard in Google Data Studio with automatic update.

Comment: Hi ! So you basically want to convert an excel file from your Drive into a Spreadsheet with a different name right?

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf Yes, but i want to keep the same always the the same ID of the spreadheet and the same sheet id. is it feasible? the reason why is because I want to import the google sheet in Google Data Studio and if the id of the sheet change I lose the connection to the file. Thanks a lot for the support :)

Comment: You cannot change the unique ID of a Drive file (for obvious reasons it has to be a random and unique value and if you would have the possibility to set it you could create two files with the same ID). Would you still be interested in a solution doing the steps I described in my previous comment?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf - yes please, my need is to import the information included in a specific excel sheet into a specific sheet in Google Sheet. My goal is to be able to keep the spreadsheetID and sheetID in order to be able to link a dashboard in google data studio with automatic update. Thanks a lot for your support :)

Comment: It is not possible to keep the spreadsheetID, however, it is possible to create new sheets in a spreadsheet document with your desired id. It must be an integer TYPE_INT32. Then, you can import your xlsx file into new spreadsheet document and copy the content of all the sheets to the new sheets generated via the Sheets API. Nevertheless, this approach is a bit cumbersome and not very effective. I think there are alternatives to satisfy your problem with Google Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a spreadsheet which sync with excel file and whenever the data update in Excel file, spreadsheet will update without change it's sheet id and use that spreadsheet to create a report on Looker (formerly Google Data Studio).

What exactly logic use

Create two spreadsheets :

1. [An excel file convert to the google spreadsheet with updation gid everytime when excel file updates ] (use Apps Script)
2. [Import data from converted file to new or second google spreadsheet] (use Apps Script).

When you import data to new spreadsheet, the sheet id will never change and you can also use it on Looker.

```
var dstFileId = 'File_id'; // file Id of Existing Spreadsheet
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet(fileName) {
fileName = fileName || "excelfile.xlsx"; //  excel_file_name.xlsx = name of specific Excel file
var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
var fileId = excelFile.getId();
var srcFileId = fileId; // file Id of Excel file
Drive.Files.update({}, dstFileId, DriveApp.getFileById(srcFileId))
};
```

Upper code for 1st spreadsheet (for convert excel file to google spreadsheet)
****** must add Drive API service ******

```
var sourceSpreadsheetID = "id_of_1st_spreadsheet";
var sourceWorksheetName = "name_of_worksheet_of_1st_spreadsheet";
var targetSpreadsheetID = "id_of_2nd_spreadsheet";
var targetWorksheetName = "name_of_worksheet_of_2nd_spreadsheet";

function importData() {
var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetID);
var thisWorksheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceWorksheetName);
var thisData = thisWorksheet.getDataRange();

var toSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
var toWorksheet = toSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetWorksheetName);
var toRange = toWorksheet.getRange(1, 1, thisData.getNumRows(), 
thisData.getNumColumns())
toRange.setValues(thisData.getValues()); 
}
```

this code for second spreadsheet (import data from 1st spreadsheet without change the sheet id)

Now you can use this new spreadsheet for create your report on Looker